# follow up question to evaluating sum with counting formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

I found that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{T}$$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{P/2}\binom{i+j}{i}$ is equal to $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{T}\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{P}{2}}\binom{i+j}{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{P}{2}}\binom{j+T+1}{T}=\binom{\frac{P}{2}+T+2}{T+1}-1$ by using the hockey-stick identity from this source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Question: I don't know where the $ -1$ comes from at the end of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{T}\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{P}{2}}\binom{i+j}{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{P}{2}}\binom{j+T+1}{T}=\binom{\frac{P}{2}+T+2}{T+1}-1$

Answer (score 1):

To apply Hockey stick, you want to start at $ { T \choose T}=1$. However, you are starting at ${ T + 1 \choose T}$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at the "Hockey Stick" identity as a special case of
the "Double Convolution" (upper & lower indices)
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( { - m\, \le } \right)\,k\left( { \le \,n} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  a - k \cr   n - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  b + k \cr   m + k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + m} \sum\limits_k {
 \left( \matrix{  n - a - 1 \cr   n - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  m - b - 1 \cr   m + k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + m} \left( \matrix{  n + m - a - b - 2 \cr   n + m \cr}  \right)
 = \left( \matrix{  a + b + 1 \cr   n + m \cr}  \right)
 \quad \left| \matrix{  \;a,b \in R \hfill \cr   \,n,m \in Z \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
where it is important to assure that the summation index be free to vary over all the range
in which the binomials are non-null: that's why I indicated the bounds in parenthesis.

Note that we are using the definition of the binomial as:
$$
\binom{x}{n}
 = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {{{x^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } } \over {n!}}} & {\left| {\;0 \le n \in \mathbb Z} \right.}  \cr 
   0 & {{\rm else}}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$

So in your case
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{i = 0}^T {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{P/2}
  {\left( \matrix{  i + j \cr   i \cr}  \right)} } \quad \quad \left( 0 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,P/2} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,i\, \le \,T}
 {\left( \matrix{  i + j \cr   i \cr}  \right)} } \quad \quad \left( 1 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,P/2} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,i\,\left( { \le \,T} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  T - i \cr   T - i \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  i + j \cr   i \cr}  \right)} } \quad \quad \left( 2 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,P/2}
 {\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   T \cr}  \right)} \quad \quad \left( 3 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,P/2}
 {\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr  j + 1 \cr}  \right)} \quad \left| {\;0 \le T + 1 \in \mathbb Z} \right.\quad \quad \quad \left( 4 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr  j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
 \quad \left| {\;0 \le P/2 \in \mathbb Z} \right.\quad \quad \quad \left( 5 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr  j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  - \left. {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  \right|_{\,j =  - 1} \quad \quad \left( 6 \right) =   \cr 
 &  = \left( \matrix{  P/2 + T + 2 \cr   P/2 + 1 \cr}  \right) - 1 \quad \left| \matrix{  \;0 \le T + 1 \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr   \;0 \le P/2 \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad \quad \quad \left( 7 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{  P/2 + T + 2 \cr   T + 1 \cr}  \right) - 1\quad \left| {\;0 \le P/2 \in \mathbb Z} \right.\quad \quad \left( 8 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{  P/2 + T + 2 \cr   T + 1 \cr}  \right) - 1\quad \quad \left( 9 \right) \cr} 
$$
where the steps are:
 - 1)  it is preferrable  to group the bounds of the sum as a unique condition;
 - 2) for the inner sum, the lower bound $0 \le i$ is implicit in the binomial, 
we introduce a second binomial to make implicit the upper bound and 
virtually have no restriction on the index range;
 - 3) we can then apply the double convolution;
 - 4) we need the upper term of the binomial to be non-negative, so to apply symmetry;
 - 5) we introduce again a binomial to make implicit the upper bound, but this need that $P/2$ be an integer;
 - 6) the lower bound is not implicit in the 2nd binomial, we need it to start from $-1$, and 
make so by adding and then subtracting the summand corresponding to $j=-1$;
 - 7) we apply the double convolution and recall the conditions on $T$ and $P$;
 - 8) with those conditions we can apply symmetry and the condition on $P$ becomes implicit;
 - 9) the binomial obtained is actually a polynomial in $P$, as such it interpolates $P$ also for real values of the same,
and can therefore be extended to $P \in \mathbb R$.

*---  additional notes  ---*

As told in the premise, to be able to apply the convolution (either simple or double) the range of the summation index 
shall be (formally) unrestricted or otherwise (practically) extend for the whole range in which the summand is not null.

So in step (4) we have that the summand is not null for $-1 \le j$, while the sum is given to start from $0=j$.
By adding the $\binom{P/2-j}{P/2-j}$ at step (5) we render implicit the upper bound at $P/2$  while for the lower bound we make
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{ - 1\, \le \,j} {}  = \sum\limits_{ - 1\, \le \,j\, \le \, - 1} {}  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,} {} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,} {}  = \sum\limits_{ - 1\, \le \,j} {}  - \sum\limits_{\,j\, = \, - 1} {}  \cr} 
$$
and pass to step (6), where now we can apply the convolution to the sum and reach yo (7).

I thought it was obvious, but ok, let's fill with data the sums above, starting from step (5).
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)} \quad \quad (5) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  - \sum\limits_{ - 1\, \le \,j\, \le \, - 1}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  - \sum\limits_{\,j\, = \, - 1}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  - \left. {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}
  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)} \right|_{\,j =  - 1} \quad \quad (6) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  - \left( \matrix{  P/2 - \left( { - 1} \right) \cr   P/2
  - \left( { - 1} \right) \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T - 1 + 1 \cr    - 1 + 1 \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  - \left( \matrix{  P/2 + 1 \cr   P/2 + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T \cr   0 \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr   j + 1 \cr}  \right)}  - 1\; \cdot \;1 =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,P/2} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  P/2 - j \cr   P/2 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  T + j + 1 \cr  j + 1 \cr}  \right)}  - 1\quad \quad (7) \cr} 
$$

Comment: There anyway you can present the substitutions and use of ur formulas more clearly? I'm finding it really hard to follow how you get from one step to the next, especially when arriving at the end result

Comment: @randomvalue: ok, I am going to put explanation of each step

Comment: The question is, HOW DOES THE -1 APPEAR???? PLEASE!!!! SHOW HOW THE TRAILING -1 COMES ABOUT IN EQUATION 7 FROM EQUATION 6. SHOW IT!!!! NO WORDPLAY

Comment: For example, you might have $ { T \choose T}=1$, so therefore you have SOMETHING - 1. That would be reasonable because it communicates WHY a 1 suddenly appears. PLEASE SHOW THE WORK

Comment: In your case, it would be $ { x - y \choose x-y }{ z + y + 1 \choose y+1 } { x - y \choose x - y} { z + y + 1 \choose y + 1} = some value - some value = {x + z + 2 \choose z + 1} - 1.$ Where some value - some value represents showing the computation of how that happened and why it's equal to that. Directly, by substituting values into variables and variables into values and simplifying the expressions (or however you do it) to reach the ${x + z + 2 \choose z + 1} - 1$ answer.

Comment: @randomvalue: hey, please calm down and make some effort also on your side to elaborate the help that it is offered to you. The $-1$ comes out very easily when you put $j=-1$, see 2nd note above

Comment: Because I was really confused. I would of rather had no answer than see something I can't understand, but I get it now and thank you so much!!